# Curve of intersection problem using lagrange multipliers

Tags: calculus, optimization, systems-of-equations, lagrange-multiplier

Let C be the curve of intersection of the following two surfaces

$$x^2+y^2=1\tag1$$

$$2x^2+4y^4+z=3\tag2$$

Find points on C which are closest to and furthest from the origin

Given that we are maximizing/minimizing distance, we can define 
$$f(x,y,z)=d^2=(x-0)^2+(y-0)^2+(z-0)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$$

My approach included that since we know that $x^2+y^2=1$, we can change $f(x,y,z)$ to $1+z^2$, and therefore only have the 2nd constraint instead of two constraints.

Taking the gradients of both, we get the following system of equations:

$$0=2λx$$

$$0=8λy$$

$$2z=λ$$

$$2x^2+4y^4+z=3$$

I am honestly at a complete loss of where to go from here. For the record, yes I could do this question without eliminating the first constraint, but I'm looking for how to do it this way. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

In fact your curve may be proyected to the plane $OYZ$ and this simplify the problem. This is so because the intersection of $(1)$ and $(2)$ is 
$$R(y,z)=4y^4-2y^2+z-1=0$$
Hence the functional to minimise is
$$f(y,z) =y^2+z^2$$

it results 
$$\vec{grad}\,f(x,y,z) = \lambda\,\vec{grad}\,R(x,y,z)$$
Resulting 
$$2\left[\begin{array}{c}
y\\
z
\end{array}\right]=\lambda\left[
\begin{array}{c}
4y(4y^2-1)\\
1\end{array}\right] \qquad with \qquad 4y^4-2y^2+z-1=0
$$
Clearly (if I have not committed any mistake) $\lambda=2z$ and the following system wil determine the values for $y$ and $z$
$$y\left[1-4z(4y^2-1)\right]=0$$
$$4y^4-2y^2+z-1=0$$
Since $x$ is not solved, we obtain it from the restriction $x^2+y^2=1$, and the global optimum will be the minimum of $|(x,y,z)|^2$ of the computed points

Comment: This is what I thought, but doesn't the fact that you made x=0 initially and solved for y=0 mean that it violates the first constraint (the one we got rid of initially), since x^2+y^2 no longer equals 1?

Comment: sorry I forgot the $y^4$!!!! Hope this is okat now... I will be editting anyways

Comment: The problem was to assume that $x=0$!! And it is not!! It doesn't take part on the optimisation but its value results from one of the two restrictions!!

Answer (score 0):

We can use the third equation to substitute for $\lambda$ in the first two:

$$ 4xz = 0 $$
$$ 16yz = 0 $$

From here, we can consider two cases: (i) $z=0$ and (ii) $z \neq 0$.

In (i), the fourth equation reduces to $$ 2x^2 + 4y^4 = 3 $$

In this solution, the objective is always $1$, so we only need to find the values of $x$ and $y$ that satisfy the displayed equation above, along with $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. It should be straightforward to solve this.

In (ii), we know that $x=y=0$, and $z=3$. However, this violates the first constraint, so this cannot be a solution.

It's easy to intuit from the objective that the solution found above has to be a minimum. I'll need to think more carefully about maxima -- will edit this when I figure that part out.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have your point on the constraints. It means that total differential of the constraints must be zero. From the first constraint
$$2xdx+2ydy=0 \Rightarrow dy=-\frac{x}{y}dx$$
From the second constraint 
$$4xdx+16y^3dy+dz=0$$
$$\Rightarrow 4xdx-16y^2xdx+dz=0$$
$$\Rightarrow dz=16y^2xdx+4xdx$$
To maximize the distance equation wrt x,y,z
$$x^2+y^2+z^2\Rightarrow 2xdx+2ydy+2zdz=0$$
Replacing dy and dz
$$2xdx-2xdx+2z(16y^2xdx+4xdx)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow 2zx(16y^2+4)dx=0$$
This equation holds for 3 case

1)$z=0$ Using the constraint equations you will find 4 points. Calculating the distance with these points you will get the global minima

2) $x=0$  Using the constraint equations you will find 2 points. Calculating the distance with these points you will see that these points are not global extremum

3) $16y^2+4=0$ Using the constraint equations you will find 4 points. Calculating the distance with these points you will get the global maxima